# Locating an element with no identifier in HTML using Selenium (Not using Xpath)

Tags: python, selenium

```
def page_nav(individual):
    indiv_home = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2] /div[2]/div[8]/a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    person_select = driver.find_elemnet(By.TAG_NAME, individual).click()
```

[`<strong>Dylan Call</strong> <-- I want to find the element based off "Dylan Call"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442Ws.png)

The code above isn't the most well written and I know that (I'm fairly new my apologies in advance)

I'm looking for a way to find the element ("individual name") in the picture above since it doesn't have a unique identifier like "name" or "id".

I am attempting to create a bot that looks through a folder, identifies the name of the individual associated with a file, and uploads the file to that respective person's profile using selenium/python. Right now, I have stored the individual name in a variable, but I want to pass that variable through the "find_elements" function. Sadly I can't just use a "By.Xpath" to locate the element since I'm trying to find it specifically on the individual's name.

Does anyone have any workarounds or better ways to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mre], clearly showing why you can't use XPath.

Comment: Can you show the code you have for now to help us understand where you are stuck ? It is not clear what element you are trying to find. Is it the link, the "strong" tag, etc... ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve your `strong` tag containing individual name using an xpath as follow

```py
individual = "Dylan Call"
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//strong[@contains(text(), "{individual}")]')
```

- Here `//` indicates that we are using relative xpath, this means we are looking for a strong tag anywhere in the html markup.
- And we specify that the strong tag we are looking for has an innerText that contains the string given by variable `individual`.

---

May I suggest an improvement, you should not use time.sleep, but [WebdriverWait in conjunction with ExpectedCondition](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/). Instead of adding an arbitrary delay to wait until a page is loaded, this allow to wait until element we are trying to find is displayed.

All together you code becomes

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

individual = "Dylan Call"

# create a wait object that will be used to wait at most 10 seconds that element appears.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# wait until the strong tag containing individual name appears.
# timeout if it did not appeared after 10 seconds.
person_select = wait.until(
    presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//strong[@contains(text(), "{individual}"]'))
)

person_select.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I avoided using wait calls since it was giving me a lot of trouble in other areas of my code. and I wanted to confirm that It wasn't the presence of the wait call in this particular instance before moving on lol